# Отрисовки статического SVG с помощью G-code на координатном устройстве

Tags: c++, qt, svg

Доброго времени суток !

Есть задача отрисовки статического SVG с помощью G-code на координатном устройстве.

Так как в Qt есть очень серьезный функционал по отрисовке SVG на различных виджетах - понимаю что должна быть возможность доступа к методам отрисовки примитивов не на уровне : QPainter::drawLine(..), QPainter::drawRect(..), QPainter::drawEllipse(..) …, а еще на более низком уровне где все фигуры (в том числе окружности, сегменты, кривые Безье и тд...) отрисовываются короткими отрезками с заданными начальными, конечными координатами и набором параметров !

- Фактически мой вопрос в том: ***какой метод нужно перегрузить для отрисовки примитивов и их параметров (QPoint,QLine) в QSvgWidget для получения контроля за отрисовкой*** ?
- Или как вариант: ***есть ли возможность получить доступ к уже отрисованным примитивам и их параметрам в QSvgWidget для движения по траектории предварительно отрисованного .svg рисунка*** ?

Буду очень благодарен за любую информацию !!!

С уважением, Юрий.

Comment: то что вас интересует, по видимому находится в классе `QPaintEngine`

Comment: тебе нужно сделать из svg G-код, я правильно понимаю? я бы сделал свой `QPaintDevice` (и `QPaintEngine`) для генерации g-кода и скормил бы его `QSvgRenderer`'у... правда, в примитивном вариате, итоговый g-код скорей всего будет субоптимальным...

Comment: Наверное было бы правильнее идти через написание своего бекэнда на базе наследования (QPainter,QPaintDevice,QPaintEngine) если я правильно понимаю ту концепцию что предлагается в Qt5.

Comment: Но мой вопрос был не об этом !!!
Я спрашивал о том что так как в Qt реализована практически полноценная работа по парсингу и прорисовке SVG на виджетах (QWidget,QImage,QSVGWidget,...) то наверняка есть на достаточно низком уровне метод который используется для рисования отрезка-примитива. и перегрузив (или переписав) его можно на его уровне сгенерировать G-Code примитива (мини-отрезка с начальными и конечными коордиратами). Что в свою очередь позволит сгенерировать G-Code всех фигур которые предлагается перегрузить в QPaintEngine для создания своего бекэнда.

Comment: @ЮрийФаков, абсолютно не понятно, зачем тебе для G-кода «*метод который используется для рисования отрезка-примитива*»?? [Ошибка XY](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-xy)?

Comment: Прошу прощения но я изначально не упомянул что хочу непосредственно связать по времени: отрисовку на виджете - генерацию g-code - вывод g-code в порт - получение подтверждение его выполнения на устройстве - передвижение по виджету маркера  !

Comment: @ЮрийФаков, в смысле «связать по времени»?

Comment: Мне нужны координаты начала и конца примитива, а так же его параметры (стиль, толщина, цвет, ...) для того что бы сформировать g-code.

Comment: В самом прямом смысле - выполнить эту последовательность одну за другой и затем уже переходить к следующей координате !

Comment: @ЮрийФаков, дык в методы `QPaintEngine`'а как раз и передаются все примитивы, которые `QSvgRenderer` находит в svg файле и рисует на `QPainter`'е... стиль/толщину/цвет можно подцепить из ассоциированного QPainter'а... По поводу последовательности — я бы разделил генерацию G-кода и его исполнение/отрисовку... но если очень хочется свалить всё в одну кучу, то можно, например, создать ещё один прокси-`QPaintDevice`, который будет переправлять отрисовку сразу на несколько backend'ов...

Comment: Совершенно с вами согласен что это наверное правильное решение в парадигме Qt ! Но как то немного громоздковато получается ! Конечно же буду пробовать решить эту задачу и классическим способом (если где то есть примеры написания бекэнда с радостью бы на них посмотрел :) ) ! Но хотелось бы попробовать реализовать тот способ о котором был вопрос !

Comment: На сколько я понимаю перегружая методы QPaintEngine я смогу работать на уровне отрисовки фигур drawPoints(..), drawLines(..), ... drawPolygon(..) и очень похоже что отрисовка конкретной точки на Q..Widget(..) ни как не будет синхронизирована по времени с отрисовкой точки на координатном устройстве ! А это не совсем то чего я хотел ! Конечно можно поступиться этим но ...

Comment: @ЮрийФаков, совершенно не факт, что «конкретная точка» вообще как-то отрисовывается на виджете — в зависимости от реализации вся линия может, например, отрисовываться как единое целое...

Comment: Добрый день ! Таки да ! Как раз это и хочется раскопать ! :) Ну во всяком случае определиться есть ли возможность получить доступ на тот уровень без модификации базовых классов - только наследованием и перегрузкой !

Comment: @ЮрийФаков, само собой, легального способа сделать туда какой-то хук не... конкретные детали реализации зависят от движка поверх которого Qt выводит графику... в случае, например, OpenGL'я вся растеризация происходит только где-то в недрах видеокарты. Как всё работает в случае софтверной растеризации — нужно смотреть, но всё равно перехватить отрисовку штатными движками адекватной возможности нет... в общем это ИМХО довольно странное и бессмысленное перректальное желание...

Comment: Ахаха ! Спасибо за новый фразеологизм ! :) Согласен ! Наверное где то оно так и есть ... ! :) Попробую соответствовать идеям Qt ! :) Не встречалось ли где более менее приличных примеров реализации QPaintDevice + QPaintEngine ?

Comment: @ЮрийФаков, можешь посмотреть реализацию `QSvgGenerator`'а — он точно также должен работь... единственное, придётся немного разобраться, как Qt контуры передаёт и с интерполяцией сплайнов...

Comment: Добрый день !

Потратив достаточное количество времени и не добившись решения своей проблемы решил продолжить свой пост ...
Есть ли у кого то из коллег опыт написания класса подобного QPrinter для вывода на него статичного SVG с помощью классов : QPaintDevice + QPaintEngine + QPainter ?
Интересует реальный опыт ! Конечно рассуждения и соображения тоже интересны ! Но опыт все же предпочтительнее ! :)

С уважением, Юрий.

Comment: Добрый день ! Судя по реакции направляющая меня подсказка в свете настоящего времени уже дело не достойное !!! :) Предлагаю компенсировать ваше время и труд по разъяснению мне нюансов написания класса подобного QPrinter разумной суммой в российских рублях !!! :) С уважением, Юрий.